# Extracting Z information from different vector layers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

I have 2 different vector layers, Layer A detailing the area of different polygons and Layer B having similar size polygons with z values instead. I would need to combine Layer A with Layer B so that I will be able to calculate the volume for the whole polygons in Layer A.
The slight problem that I am having at the moment is that the polygons in Layer B with the z values do not precisely coincide with the ones from Layer A. Also, in some areas some of the polygons, which are represented by Layer A with 50 polygons, are represented in Layer B with just one because the height value is the same. The spaces between polygons do not have values.

How can I extract the Z values from Layer B so that they will be included into Layer A keeping the exact same number of polygons?

Answer (score 1):

Try a [join by location](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Spatial_joins_by_feature_type/005s00000032000000/) (right click on layer A) and you should be able to pull the same z value from B onto multiple layer A polygons. There are a few options to play around with (I don't have arc open to check at the moment) but hopefully one of them will be what you are after.

Comment: Hi MAJ742, thanks for your answer. I have tried to perform the 'join by location' task by unfortunately I would need some kind of interpolation feature in order to 'blend' the z values onto Layer A as the polygons on layer A and B are not an exact match in size so basically I will need to tell arc to use the 'closest' z values on Layer B and used them to create a z field in Layer A for the polygons which are the nearest to the ones in Layer B. Hope I havent confused everyone... Thanks